# How to convert appsettings array to readonlycollection

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings

I'm trying to get the following from my appsettings:

```
    "ApiKeys": {
        "Keys": [
          {
            "Key": "06795D9D-A770-44B9-9B27-03C6ABDB1BAE",
            "Roles": [ "Manager" ]
          }
        ]
}
```

I'm using the following:

```
public class ApiKey
    {
        public ApiKey(string key, IReadOnlyCollection<string> roles)
        {
            Key = key ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
            Roles = roles ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(roles));
        }
        public string Key { get; }
        public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Roles { get; }
    }
```

.............somewhere else in the code......................

```
_config.GetSection("ApiKeys:Keys").Get<List<ApiKey>>();
```

It works when I have the Roles as a standard 'List' but I really want it as the a 'ReadOnlyCollection'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you do `var readonlyList = list.AsReadOnly()`?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

```
var settings = _config.GetSection("ApiKeys:Keys").Get<List<ApiKey>>();
return new ReadOnlyCollection<ApiKey>(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, binding to a type requires a type with a default constructor since the binder will use `Activator.CreateInstance` to [create the instance](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/v3.1.6/src/Configuration/Config.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L376) it binds to. So you cannot have the constructor like that.

Furthermore, the binder explicitly skips any properties [that do not have a setter](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/v3.1.6/src/Configuration/Config.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L203-L208), so you cannot have read-only properties and expect the binder to work.

The only reason why your code doesn’t fail is because you are binding to a `List<ApiKey>` so the failure from the `ApiKey` binding is simply swallowed.

If you change your type so it has a default constructor and setters, then binding to it will work, even with a read-only collection.

```
public class ApiKey
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

If you don’t want your ApiKey type to be mutable afterwards, consider converting it into another read-only type after binding it from configuration.

Note that in the context of the related options pattern, mutable options types are usually desired because they can be configured from multiple sources (e.g. from configuration, then from a configure action, and maybe even with a post-configure action).

Comment: You can bind to private properties `.Get<Something>(c => c.BindNonPublicProperties = true)` And expose anything you like really